# IBM Security Access Manager (ISAM) Installation, firmware image error can't open dev/sda

Tags: isam

My manager has asked me to install ISAM and he has provided me the VMs on server.
I am accessing them through vsphere client. I don't find it that tough but the initial error is so interrupting
I am attaching snpas below. Can anyone tell me why it is can't partition the disk
[fdisk: can't open 'dev/sda/': No such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BW04.png)

[The firmware image could not be installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e9l9.png)

[No boot filename received, Operating system not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuBeZ.png)

Comment: You might get more traction asking this question over at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) which is also on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @e_i_pi thankyou so much. I'll do so.